# Need to maximize the zoom-in amount and minimize the zoom-out amount

Tags: css, zooming

I need to maximize the zoom-in amount **and** minimize the zoom-out amount.

In short, I don't want the text etc to get too **too large** *or* **too small** (so it cannot be read).

**The question is How?**

Right now, I have no limit on the amount of zooming in the user can do.

Safari isn't too terrible, but **Chrome is horrible** only because it allows the user to make **a super super narrow window**. As a direct result, the words inside a oval break almost to the point that there is sometimes **one letter per line**.

Here is what normal, no zooming looks like:

[image: normal, no zooming]

Here is what it looks like after being zoomed in to the max:

[image]

I know what the problem is, that is, it gets zoomed in too far such that the fully zoomed in size exceeds the width of the enclosure.

It is for this reason, I wish to limit the damage by preventing the zoomed in from going to far. Ditto for zooming out to something way too small.

**The question is How?**

**HTML:**

```
<section class="roundedTextCornersWrapper centerBlock">

    <div class="roundedTextCorners centerBlockContents">
        <div class ="headerText superLongStuff" lang="en">
MY VERY OWN GUARDIAN ANGEL!<p>

MY LOVE SONG FOREVER!!
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.roundedTextCornersWrapper {
    /* + a tad extra more push up above .restofContent */
    padding-bottom: 2.0em;
}

.roundedTextCorners {
    border:           0.3125em #994c00 solid;
    border-radius:    0.625em;
    background-color: #994c00;
    color:            #fff;
}

.headerText {
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica;
    font-size:   1.60em;
    color:       #fff;

 /*
    vertical-align: middle;   // does not work here??
 */
    padding:     1em 0em 0em 0em;   /* a tweak on padding-top */
    text-align:  center;
}

.superLongStuff {   
    overflow-wrap:   break-word;
    word-wrap:       break-word;
}
```

Comment: If the user wants to make the website unreadable on their screen, let them. It's their loss! Also, Firefox has the ability to set a minimum and maximum user zoom level in its about:config, and that's good; _that's_ where this setting should be, not in some random webpage. No offence meant.

Comment: Now, your comment is the very 1st one that really makes any sense. In short, I cannot possibly try to circumvent every "silly" move of the user.  I totally thank you!!!  With that said, here is my web page at this point:  http://www.lovesongforever.com/lovestory

Comment: That said, you can restrict the font size on very narrow screens by clever use of `vw` in a media query. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vmvqsaL1/2/), would that help?